# Refactoring parsing the XML from DOM parser to SAX parser

Tags: xml, dom, namespaces, sax

Legacy code is using DOM parser to parse a very big XML file.

Workflow:
1. Clean up the namespace from the document. 
document.accept(new NameSpaceCleaner());
**This is namespace cleaner class.**
final class NameSpaceCleaner extends VisitorSupport
{
    @Override
    public void visit(Document document)
    {
        ((DefaultElement) document.getRootElement()).setNamespace(Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE);
        document.getRootElement().additionalNamespaces().clear();
    }

```
@Override
public void visit(Attribute node)
{
     if (node.toString().contains("xmlns") || node.toString().contains("xsi:")) {
        node.detach();
    }
}

@Override
public void visit(Element node)
{
    if (node instanceof DefaultElement) {
        ((DefaultElement) node).setNamespace(Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE);
    }
}
```

Not sure how do I clean up the namespace using SAX parser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your code is doing: the class DefaultElement seems to be a Xerces-internal thing and I don't know exactly when your test "node instanceof DefaultElement" succeeds. I'll assume it is testing whether the node is in the default namespace, and that you are trying to move all nodes in the default namespace to be in no namespace.

I'm not going to offer you a SAX solution because I don't have the time or energy to write such low-level code, but if you want to do it with XSLT 3.0 streaming then it's:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @xsi:*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()!='']">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @xsi:*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```